# Swift 3 ambigous use of 'row'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I just migrated to swift 3 and i am getting this error ambiguous use of `row` on `indexPath` same on `section` and `item`.

Other properties are just working like `count`.

Most probably it is because of inferring.

[image]

Here is the ambiguity:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the full log screenshot:

[image]

I am using `AlecrimCoreData` third party and it has the following extension:

```
// MARK: - IndexPath extensions

    extension IndexPath {

        public init(forRow row: Int, inSection section: Int) {
            self.init(indexes: [section, row])
        }

        //public var section: Int { return self[0] }
        public var row: Int { return self[1] }

    }
```

If I just comment out this line `public var row: Int { return self[1] }` my code compiles successfully.

Comment: Can you show the full compiler error message from the Report navigator?

Comment: When you click on the "Found this candidate" messages, what does each of them show you?

Comment: It shows nothing.

Comment: Please go to the **Report navigator,** select the build, and click icon on the right which opens the full textual output of the compiler.

Comment: As you already found out, AlecrimCoreData defines a `row` property for `IndexPath`, which conflicts with the existing property. I have no idea why AlecrimCoreData does that, removing the definition *is* the solution.

Comment: @MartinR if you answer it. I will mark it as correct and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlecrimCoreData defines a `row` property for `IndexPath`, which conflicts with the [existing `row` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath/1614853-row) defined in UIKit.

Remove the definition in AlecrimCoreData to solve the problem.