# Swift unwrapped values still show as Optional

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I'm struggling to get name values to display without the `Optional(...)`. I thought I was unwrapping them, but I can't get rid of the optional. I found a solution on StackOverflow, but in that situation, there was an `as?` involved, which isn't the case here. The offending code is below. Is there any way I can unwrap these? I am assuming I'm missing something obvious. Thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! ClientCell

    cell.setBackground()

    let clientKey = clientSectionTitles[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section]
    if let clientValues = clientDict[clientKey] {
        if self.sortBy == "First" {
            cell.clientName.text = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName! + " " + clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].lastName!
        } else {
            cell.clientName.text = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].lastName! + ", " + clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName!
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

*Edit:
Here is the code that builds the dictionary:

```
func createClientDict() {
    var clientName: String?
    clientDict          = [String: [Client]]()
    clientSectionTitles = [String]()

    if self.sortBy == "First" {
        apiResults.sort (by: { $0.firstName < $1.firstName })
    } else {
        apiResults.sort (by: { $0.lastName < $1.lastName })
    }

    for c in apiResults {
        if self.sortBy == "First" {
            clientName = "\(c.firstName!) \(c.lastName!)"
        } else {
            clientName = "\(c.lastName!), \(c.firstName!)"
        }

        // Get the first letter of the name and build the dictionary
        let clientKey = clientName!.substring(to: clientName!.characters.index(clientName!.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
        if var clientValues = clientDict[clientKey] {
            clientValues.append(c)
            clientDict[clientKey] = clientValues
        } else {
            clientDict[clientKey] = [c]
        }
    }

    // Get the section titles from the dictionary's keys and sort them in ascending order
    clientSectionTitles = [String](clientDict.keys)
    clientSectionTitles = clientSectionTitles.sorted { $0 < $1 }
}
```

*Edit: I should also mention that this only happens in Swift 3. It worked fine in Swift 2.2.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but why are you needlessly casting `indexPath` to an `NSIndexPath`?

Comment: Because I get the error `Ambiguous use of 'row'` if I don't. I would love a better solution. This started happening after migration to Swift 3.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Sam_M, I'm using 8.2.1

Comment: Using any third party libraries?

Comment: related to your question, when storing the names in the `clientValues` check to see if they are being added as optional inside a string.

Comment: Yes. Alamofire, SwiftyJSON, Eureka, and a few others.

Comment: @Sam_M, I have edited my question and added the method that builds the dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy, according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554840/swift-3-ambigous-use-of-row), the problem with `Ambiguous use of 'row'` is caused by AlecrimCoreData.

Comment: As – in real life – any person / client is supposed to have a first and last name why do you use optionals at all? Unfortunately many developers use optionals as an alibi to avoid writing initializers, but this is very bad programming habit. Consider to use non-optional `String` for first and last name. This resolves magically the issue in the question.

Comment: Thats the kicker. They are not declared as optionals. They are non-optional and are assigned values in the initializer. That's why this error seems so unusual.

Answer (score 1):

the following is from the Swift Programming Language Collection Types docmentation:

> You can also use subscript syntax to retrieve a value from the
>   dictionary for a particular key. Because it is possible to request a
>   key for which no value exists, a dictionary’s subscript returns an
>   optional value of the dictionary’s value type. If the dictionary
>   contains a value for the requested key, the subscript returns an
>   optional value containing the existing value for that key. Otherwise,
>   the subscript returns nil:

so `clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]` returns an optional value

try

```
cell.clientName.text = (clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName!)!
```

*edited - actually better to use optional binding :

```
if let fname = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName! {
   cell.clientName.text = fname }
```

Comment: I get the error `Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Client'` with the `?` in there. If I take the `?` out, it compiles, but then displays the value as optional.

Comment: No luck. I tried the following and still got an optional value. How is this possible? `let fname: String!
            
            fname = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName!
            print(fname!)
            cell.clientName.text = fname!`

Comment: the console display is `Optional("Ed")`

Comment: Somewhere something is being defined as an optional optional??? Then try force unwrapping it twice!! Does that work... find a way to get the name printed. Then figure out where the trouble is....

Comment: It turns out, embarrassingly enough, that the problem was not on the retrieval of the value, but rather on the save. It had saved `Optional(\"Ed\")"` to the database, and was just retrieving back what was saved. I will delete this question, as it won't be of any help to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to the `clientKey` variable which has optional value. Try unwrapping that before using it like below :

```
if let clientKey = clientSectionTitles[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section] {
    if let clientValues = clientDict[clientKey] {
        if self.sortBy == "First" {
            cell.clientName.text = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName! + " " + clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].lastName!
        } else {
            cell.clientName.text = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].lastName! + ", " + clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName!
        }
    }
}
```

=== EDIT: ===

```
 let clientKey = clientSectionTitles[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section] 
        if let clientValues = clientDict[clientKey] {
            if self.sortBy == "First" {
                cell.clientName.text = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName! + " " + clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].lastName!
            } else {
                cell.clientName.text = clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].lastName! + ", " + clientValues[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].firstName!
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'` on the first line.

Comment: @kuzdu, I tried that and it still displays as optional.

Comment: @Lastmboy, on which line are you getting the error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' " ? plz let me know,

Comment: Edited the answer, let me know what happens now.

Comment: @Tushar, as I mentioned below, the problem was apparently on the save to the database. It was saving the `Optional(\"Ed\")` as data and was simply retrieving that. The value itself was not actually option. Very embarrassing. Thanks for all your help. I will delete this question as it won't likely be of use to anyone.